# Python printing a procedure

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to print a procedure in Python. How do I print it?
  Here is my code

```
def proc(a,b):
    if test(a):
        return b
    return a

print proc(a,b)
```

But I get this error:

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can print a function in Python using `print(myFunctionName)`. If the output you get from that isn't what you want, please provide more detail regarding what output you expect.

Comment: Thanks for showing us the output that you're currently getting. Now, what output do you _want_ to see?

Comment: I actually don't know what should I get really. I was given this code to try things on.

Comment: Wait I made something wrong. Let me edit it back

Comment: Edited it. As I said I was given this code and I don't know what should it give me. So thats why I am trying to print.

Comment: This code would never work. `a` and `b` are local variables to your function `proc`, as in they only exist within that function and not outside of it. So when you try `print(a,b)` outside of the function, nothing will happen as a and b don't exist. place print inside the function (before the return statement) and it should work. This is very very basic level python so it may be worth looking up a tutorial or a free online course to learn more.

Comment: When I tried this. No changes.

Comment: Worth noting my print statement was Python 3.x, not 2.7 What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is the name of the local variable used to hold the value of the first argument passed to the function when it is called. When actually *calling* it, you need an actual value, or a variable defined in the scope where the function is *called*. For example:

```
def proc(a,b):
    if test(a):
        return b
    return a

x = 6
print proc(x, 7)
```

Now when `proc` is called, the value of the variable `x` and the value `7` are passed to `proc`. Inside `proc`, `a` will have the same value as `x` (at the time of the call) in the calling scope, and similarly `b` will have the value `7`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call `proc` and view the result, then there are two things you need to know:

- You call a function by typing its name, followed by a pair of parentheses that contains the function's arguments: `proc(23, 42)`
- You can print the result of an expression by typing `print`, followed by a pair of parentheses containing the expression: `print(4 + 8 * sqrt(15) - 26)`.

Combine these two principles to view the result of a function call.

```
print(proc(23, 42))
```